# NuGet.exe pack packs into a subfolder I don't need

Tags: directory, nuget, pack

When I execute

```
C:\Tools\Nuget\NuGet.exe pack C:\SomePath\Server\Server.nuspec -OutputDirectory D:\NuGet\Repository -basePath C:\SomePath\Server -Version 8.1.0.1 -NoPackageAnalysis
```

The created .nupkg file contains a folder called Server.
How can I call NuGet.exe pack so that the contents of my folder Server is packed at the root of the package and not in a subfolder Server?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the standard layout of folders in the Server folder? ( tools, lib, content)

Otherwise

- Is BasePath necessary ?
- What happens if you call pack with nuspec file? No parameters

Comment: I have a content folder, but no tools or lib. The same thing happens when I just pass the nuspec file as a parameter. If I leave out the -NoPackageAnalysis it complains about the missing lib folder.

Comment: try adding the lib folder for sure... I remember having problems if that one wasn't defined

Comment: I tried adding the lib folder. The only difference is that the Server folder inside the NuGet package now contains a lib folder.

Comment: Does the nuspec file specify the path? maybe you can cheat and remove them with a text-editor yourself...

Comment: No. There is no path in the nuspec file. It looks like the one on the Octopus website: http://octopusdeploy.com/documentation/packaging/octopack
But I am creating the nuspec file myself in a Powershell script. I could change it if that would help.